# Twitter Bootstrap nav Collapse drop-down menu is overlapping content?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, responsive-design

I am using a template based off of Twitter Bootstrap for a site I'm building (here's the link: [rwphoto](http://goo.gl/0YqZp)), but I am having some trouble with the mobile drop-down menu. It overlaps instead of pushing content down if I change the navbar-inner div to 194px to fit the height of the repeating image I'm using. I am just not sure exactly why this is a problem. I've looked around, but can't seem to find a solution to this.

Additionally, how would I center the .brand element (logo) in mobile, instead of having it to the left? And how would I get the nav links centered vertically, and horizontally between the logo and the right edge of the screen?

*sigh*... Sorry, first time using Bootstrap, obviously... :/

Comment: I don't see a drop down even if I hover over the nav links.

Comment: If you resize the browser (or if you're viewing it on a mobile device), there will be a button with three lines. That's the menu button. Click that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Centering logo, implement this css code to the referred class...

```
.container { position:relative; }    
.brand { text-align: center;    width: 97%;}

.navbar .btn-navbar {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

For Centering, the nav links,

```
.nav-collapse .nav > li > a {
    margin: 12px 0 !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And for the drop-down overlay issue, add this,

```
.nav-collapse { padding-top: 1em; }
```

Comment: Check this link, you can customize that as you wish... http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: What I mean is I want the logo centered once it has switched to maybe 768px wide. It should stay on the left for a wider screen. I'm fairly new to media queries, but I imagine that is where they come in, yes?

I tried the above code, but the links don't really line up vertically in the navbar and horizontally between the logo the right side of the screen.

Also, the `padding-top` set to `1em` didn't seem to do the trick. :(

Comment: Ah! I looked at the code for `.navbar-inner` on the official page for Twitter, and the height is set by `min-height`, **not** `height`. Simple mistake. I changed the `.navbar-inner` to `min-height: 194px`, and that did the trick! So, now the only issue is using the media queries for the logo, and then getting those links centered the right way...

Comment: I'll check that out.. I wonder if a width percentage and margin-top will work for the links?